# Create Apptainer container with environment.yml without creating a new conda environment within container

Tags: anaconda, containers, apptainer

Hi so I am trying to create a container with apptainer. The server hosts would like to prevent the creation of conda environments within a container.

However, I only have a environment file. Which would result in the creation of a new environment.

My current idea is to remove the name within the `env.yml` and then install the env by:

```
%post
    conda env update -f environment.yml
```

but that does not work. Because I would need to specify which environment to update.
A second option is to locally install the `environment.yml`. Then create `requirements.txt` which I could install like so:

```
%post
    conda install -y --file requirements.txt
```

Here is my problem, that I have to mange many different channels from which I have to install the dependencies. Especially, I have to also install pip dependencies. Which I could do manually, but I would rather find a elegant way to do so.

Comment: This problem seems underspecified to me. How does the host even enforce this? I'm not an apptainer user, but it looks like a successor to Singularity, which basically runs any Docker image. I would get clarification from the sysadmin(s) on what is the actual concern. I expect following best practices - i.e., diligence w.r.t. cleaning up, [as illustrated here](https://uwekorn.com/2021/03/01/deploying-conda-environments-in-docker-how-to-do-it-right.html) - would be sufficient. Otherwise, I'm not sure there's more to suggest than "use `apt-get`".

Comment: Oh, and absolutely don't use *Anaconda* in a container - that's total bloat. [Micromamba](https://mamba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/micromamba.html) is designed for such DevOps.

Comment: Well okay I can also easily replace conda with miniconda, however, that does not solve any of the issues described.

Comment: So you are allowed to have a single Conda environment? Then use Micromamba to create a single environment.

Comment: Okay I figured now that the apptainer is using te base environment. So I can just update the base environment using /opt/conda/bin/conda env update --name base --file environment.yml --prune